# cosine similarity preprocesing task

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have recently started with NLP. As part of cosine similarities calculation I have to complete the following task:

```
# Convert the sentences into bag-of-words vectors.
sent_1 = dictionary.doc2bow(sent_1)
sent_2 = dictionary.doc2bow(sent_2)
sent_3 = dictionary.doc2bow(sent_3)
```

I have more than 10000 different sentences (documents), so I want to generete a code which iterates automatically over documents.
I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
sent_X = []
for i in documents:
    sent_X .append(dictionary.doc2bow(simple_preprocess(i)))
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the exected output? What dosn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works fine. I think the problem is that the resulting output isn't what you expect. So, let's see a simple example and see how this works:

```
>>> from gensim import corpora
>>> from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

>>> documents = ["apple apple apple banana",
...              "hello hello this is a document"]
>>> dictionary = corpora.Dictionary([simple_preprocess(line) for line in documents])
>>>
>>> sent_X = []
>>> for i in documents:
...     sent_X .append(dictionary.doc2bow(simple_preprocess(i)))
>>> sent_X
[[(0, 3), (1, 1)], [(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 1)]]
```

I think this result (output of `sent_X`) caused your confusion. Let's see a more clarified result

```
>>> for doc in sent_X:
    print([[dictionary[id_], freq] for id_, freq in doc])
[['apple', 3], ['banana', 1]]
[['document', 1], ['hello', 2], ['is', 1], ['this', 1]]
```